# Handle Multiple Languages with xml.tree.ElementTree Module

Tags: python, xml, csv, unicode, elementtree

I'm attempting to parse an XML file and print sections of the contents into a CSV file for manipulation with a program such as Microsoft Excel. The issue I'm running into is that the XML file contains multiple alphabets (Arabic, Cyrillic, etc.) and I'm getting confused over what encoding I should be using.

```
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

file = 'example.xml'
csvf = open(os.path.splitext(file)[0] + '.csv', "w+", newline='')
csvf.seek(0)
csvw = csv.writer(csvf, delimiter=',')
root = ET.parse(file).getroot()
name_base = root.find("name")
name_base_string = ET.tostring(name_base, encoding="unicode", method="xml").strip()
csv_data.append(name_base_string)
csvf.close()
```

I do not know what encoding to pass to the tostring() method. If I use 'unicode' it returns a unicode python string and all is well when writing to the CSV file, but Excel seems to handle this really improperly (all editors on windows and linux seem to see the character sets properly). If I use encoding 'UTF-8' the method returns a bytearray, which if I pass to the CSV writer without decoding I receive the string b'stuff' in the csv document.

Is there something I'm missing here? Does Excel just suck at handling certain encodings? I've read up on how UTF-8 is an encoding and Unicode is just a character set (that you can't really compare them) but I'm still confused.

Comment: You haven't shown us what's in example.xml and the `csv_data` variable is undefined, so we cannot run the code in the question. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Anyway, if you have an element object called `name_base` whose text content you want to add to the CSV file, use `name_base.text`. Using `ET.tostring()` looks strange.